# Sorting results of coordinates (lat and long) by proximity

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page that loads a lot of markers in a map (Google Maps).

The markers when clicked open InfoWindows that have "previous" and "next" links, which the user can use to navigate the markers. Right now I'm not using any particular order and the map moves all over the place when the next/prev marker is too far.

What I'd like to do is to use the coordinates in some way that the query already returns the results ordered by proximity (some combination of lat and long) so that the map moves "less" when the user moves from one marker to the next.

I may or may not have a central point of reference to calculate the proximity/distance from. Do I need one?

---

EDIT(some more info):
Imagine that I have a query such as:

```
select id, name, lat, long from whatever;
```

I'd like to have something in the lines of:

```
select id, name, somecalc(lat, long) as coord from whatever order by coord;
```

So when I process this query in my code and generate the markers, each "prev" and "next" link (which I build as a linked list) would have markers the closest to them as possible. What I need is the `somecalc` above.

Comment: What does your existing code look like? What have you tried to implement this?   How many markers?  Do they change?  Do you need to dynamically order them every time you start, or can you manually order your input data to meet your criteria?

Comment: I'll add some more info.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Good old Pythagoras is your friend here: Let's say we start from coords (start_lat, start_long). This could be a random first result for example. If you want to order your results by distance to that coordinates you simply have to

```
 SELECT 
      id, Name,
      SQRT(POW(start_lat - lat, 2) + POW(start_long - Long, 2)) AS distance
 FROM 
      whatever
 ORDER BY 
      distance
```